# Why the function don't work on the string?

Tags: c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void chuli(string a)
{
    a.erase(0,2);
}

int main()
{
    string a = "012345";
    a = chuli(a);
    cout << a; 
}
```

I am beginner in C++, I want to know why after this function, this string doesn't change. Is this something about the namespace?

Answer (score 3):

The string is passed by value, so your action is applied to a copy of your object.
If you need to modify your value, you need to pass it by pointer or by reference:

```
void chuli(string &a)
{
    a.erase(0,2);
}

void chuli(string *a)
{
    a->erase(0,2);
}
```